# Put TextView outside the screen

Tags: android, layout

Let's suppose I have some RelativeLayout and ScrollView like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I append TextView to the bottom of this layout so this TextView will lie outside the screen, and just under the vertical scroll?

As the result I cannot see this TextView, but if I scroll I will see immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you need another ScrollView, the structure should be like this:

RelativeLayout>ScrollView>Linearout>ScrollView/TextView

You need another ScrollView to hold the origin ScrollView and Textview. A ScrollView can only own a child view, so you need a LinearLayout to hold them.

It should be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        <LinearLayout
            <ScrollView
                <!--Blah blah-->
            </ScrollView>
            <TextView
                <!--Blah blah-->
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```